# Can't find the syntax error in this SQLite statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, command-line

I am writing an Android app and need a database for it. I will have three tables but only managed to make one right now. I do them in the console to debug and to implement them in my Javacode later. The following statements were succesfull:

```
sqlite3 progressapp.db

CREATE TABLE Z_Type(_Z_T_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
Description TEXT NOT NULL, Unit TEXT NOT NULL);
```

But now I want to refference the PK of T_Type in my other table:

```
CREATE TABLE goals (_Z_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Title TEXT NOT NULL,
Type INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(Type) REFERENCES Z_Type(_Z_T_ID),
Timeframe TEXT, Goaldate INTEGER);
```

Is `Type INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(Type) REFERENCES Z_Type(_Z_T_ID)` a valid SQLite Statement in Android? It says "Error: near "Timeframe": syntax error" But I simply can't find it due to lack with SQL Experience I guess.

Is there a better way to reference the FK maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`CREATE TABLE goals (_Z_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Title TEXT NOT NULL,
Type INTEGER NOT NULL,Timeframe TEXT, Goaldate INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Type) REFERENCES Z_Type(_Z_T_ID));`

I think that the order is important.
For further documentation you could visit sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 0):

You can define the reference as part of the column definition

```
CREATE TABLE goals (_Z_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Title TEXT NOT NULL,
Type INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Z_Type(_Z_T_ID),
Timeframe TEXT, Goaldate INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a [sqlite CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) statement, column definitions come first and table constraints only after that.

`FOREIGN KEY(Type) REFERENCES Z_Type(_Z_T_ID)` is a table constraint that should go at the end.